# Origine di menabò

Tags: etymology

***[Menabò](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=menab%C3%B2)*** è un termine usato in in campo tipografico/giornalistico col significato di:

> - schema di lavoro di un progetto grafico, con le indicazioni necessarie per comporre i testi e inserire le illustrazioni
> - modello per l’impaginazione di un lavoro a stampa, costituito da fogli su cui sono incollati nell’ordine esatto i testi in bozza ritagliati e le copie (stamponi) delle illustrazioni
>
> ***Etimologia***: ← voce milan.; propr. ‘mena i buoi’, prob. nel senso di ‘guida per la stampa’.

(Garzanti)

[image]

Qualcuno ha informazione più precise sull’origine di questo insolito termine? Cosa c’entrano, se c’entrano,  i buoi?

Comment: Sull'origine non saprei...
ritengo che  "menare" sia usato nel senso di "condurre" (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/menare/) e per associazione, il bozzetto di stampa ricorda i solchi lasciati dall'aratro per dividere il campo, non so...

Comment: Su Wikipedia ho trovato:  "Il nome deriva dal modo in cui i giornalisti del Corriere della Sera chiamavano i tipografi". Questo conferma l'origine milanese del termine... si tratterebbe quindi di uno sfottò: i tipografi (ignoranti come buoi) devono essere condotti passo a passo

Comment: https://books.google.de/books?id=BWtCDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA300&dq=menab%C3%B2+buoi&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVr8mA6M3TAhXDVBQKHYm2DQQQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=menab%C3%B2%20buoi&f=false 
---
http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/menabo
---
https://books.google.de/books?id=D90BBUjPlW4C&pg=PA159&dq=menab%C3%B2+buoi&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVr8mA6M3TAhXDVBQKHYm2DQQQ6AEITDAG#v=onepage&q=menab%C3%B2%20buoi&f=false
---
(personalmente, e aldifuorí dell editoria, un menabó mi suona di un "For Dummies", e suona anche bene date le spiegazioni dell origine del termine..)

Comment: Non sono sicura che si tratti di uno sfottò verso i tipografi... I buoi mi hanno fatto venire in mente l'Indovinello Veronese, uno dei primi testi che documentano il passaggio dal latino all'italiano. In queste righe, l'amanuense parla del suo lavoro: «Boves se pareba Alba pratalia araba Et albo versorio teneba Et negro semen seminaba» (così la trascrizione della Treccani, http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/indovinello-veronese/)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi - ignorante come un bue? L'hai mai sentito dire?

Comment: @gio ignorante oppure tardo, es.

https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/bue#Proverbi_e_modi_di_dire

http://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=BUE100